# Azure Cosmos DB asking for partition key for stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using GUID Id as my partition key and I am facing problem when I am trying to run a stored procedure. To run a store procedure I need to provide partition key ans I am not sure what value should I provide in this case? Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a
>   single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the
>   documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned,
>   then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a
>   single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then
>   include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the
>   transaction must run under.

You could refer to the description above which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions).

As @Rafat Sarosh said, `GUID Id` is not an appropriate `partitioning key`. Based on your situation , `city` may be more appropriate.You may need to adjust your database `partitioning scheme` because the partitioning key can not be deleted or modified after you have defined it.

I suggest you [exporting your data](http://Azure%20Cosmos%20DB:%20Data%20migration%20tool) to `json` file then [import](http://Azure%20Cosmos%20DB:%20Data%20migration%20tool) to a new collection which is partitioned by `city` via [Azure Cosmos DB Data migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#Prerequisites).

Hope it helps you.

---

Just for summary:

***Issue:***

Unable to provide specific partition key value when executing sql to query documents.

**Solution:**

1.Set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to `true` when executing query sql.(has performance bottleneck)

2.Consider setting a frequently queried field as a partitioning key.

Comment: I do understand the concept of partition key, but still my first scenario is still a puzzle, are you saying now I have to pass all combinations of cities while executing the store procedure? Which to me doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It will be great if you let me know how should I execute a select query based on tracking id when city is my partition key. That would be great help

Comment: @Dadwals Let's talk in this chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165266/jaydadwals

Comment: I just joined the chat room

Comment: @JayGong  I have a scenario like  I have to delete a document with different partiotion key (Suppose my partition key is vehicle type), If i have to delete 10 types of vehicle, can i do it in a single go  or do I need to run the sp 10 times ?

Answer (score 0):

Example your partition key is /id

and your cosmos document is

```
{
  "id" : abcde
}
```

When store procedure run, you need to paste: abcde value

So if you want your store procedure running cross partition, it can't
Answer from cosmos team
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/33550159-support-stored-procedure-execution-over-all-partit